# What determines whether I can use the comparison operators?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I wrote a generic extension method to see if a Key is in a certain range:

```
public static bool IsInRange(this Key key, Key lowerBoundKey, Key upperBoundKey )
{
    return lowerBoundKey <= key && key <= upperBoundKey;
}
```

That seems simple enough, but suppose I want to write a generic method equivalent that will work with any type that can use the `<=` comparison operator:

```
public static bool IsInRange(this T value, T lowerBound, T upperBound )
{
    return lowerBound <= value && value <= upperBound;
}
```

How do I apply `where T : ISomethingIDontKnow` so I can make this compile?

Comment: Not sure but if it implement IComparable might be sufficient

Comment: `where T : IComparable` should be enough for this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting the method to a generic method with `where T : IComparable` should be enough for this to work.

```
public static bool IsInRange<T>(this T value, T lowerBound, T upperBound ) 
    where T : IComparable {

    return value != null && lowrBound != null && upperBound !=null
           && lowerBound.CompareTo(value) <= 0 && value.CompareTo(upperBound) <= 0;
}
```